# Get all the nested arrays from main array and merge each of them according to keys Knockout.Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am trying to merge all the nested array with same keys, there are more then 100 nested arrays, I want them all to be merged when key is same.

I have tried to merge arrays with a little harder way (which I don't want because I have 100 plus nested arrays).

```
var keys = [];
var stream = {arr1: [], arr2:[], arr3:[]}; // Nested Arrays
for(var i =0;i<arr_main.length;i++){
  for(var key in arr_main[i]){
   if(keys.find(x => x === key))
   {
     if(key == "arr1")
     {
     let arr = stream.arr1
     let union = [...new Set([...arr, ...arr_main[i][key]])];
     stream.arr1 = union
     }
     else if(key == "arr2")
     {
     let arr = stream.arr2
     let union = [...new Set([...arr, ...arr_main[i][key]])];
     stream.arr2 = union
     }
     else if(key == "arr3")
     {
     let arr = stream.arr3
     let union = [...new Set([...arr, ...arr_main[i][key]])];
     stream.arr3 = union
     }
   }else{
     if(key == "arr1")
     stream.arr1 = arr_main[i][key]
     else if(key == "arr2")
     stream.arr2 = arr_main[i][key]
     else if(key == "arr3")
     stream.arr3 = arr_main[i][key]
   }
   if(!keys.find(x => x === key))
   keys.push(key);
  }
 }
```

Expected Output:

```
{"arr1":[{"val1":"val1","val2":"val2"},{"val1":"val111","val2":"val222"}],"arr2":[{"val1":"val11","val2":"val22"},{"val1":"val1","val2":"val2"}],"arr3":[{"val1":"val111","val2":"val222"},{"val1":"val11","val2":"val22"}]}
```

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbjcsar6/13/) https://jsfiddle.net/kbjcsar6/13/

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Comment: Question Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array. Inside, loop through the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of each object. Add each key to the accumulator and merge them.

```js
const input=[{arr1:[{val1:"val1",val2:"val2"}],arr2:[{val1:"val11",val2:"val22"}],arr3:[{val1:"val111",val2:"val222"}]},{arr1:[{val1:"val111",val2:"val222"}],arr2:[{val1:"val1",val2:"val2"}],arr3:[{val1:"val11",val2:"val22"}]}];

const output = input.reduce((acc, o) => {
  Object.entries(o).forEach(([key, arr]) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key].push(...arr)
  })
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(output)
```